# How to send the value of a variable in one window to a new window using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JavaScript code -

```
    function addOnClickEventHandler()
     {
      var userNameElement = document.getElementById("currentUser");
      var userName = userNameElement.value; // send this value to "chatWindow"

      window.open("chatWindow.html", "Chat Window", "resizable=0,width=700,height=600");
     }
```

Now, how do I send the value of userName to "chatWindow"? Also, how to access this value once it has been sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the window being opened you can refer to the parent window as follows:
var oWinCaller = top.opener;
With this reference you can then get whatever you want from the opening window when the new window opens.

Comment: So, for eg. oWinCaller.userName gets me the username? But the new window is HTML. The HTML will treat this as plaintext. How to get around this?

Comment: You could place an element e.g. a hidden field in the new window's html and write the value from the parent into into it.

Comment: @5arx Will this do? <input type="hidden" value = oWinCaller.userName />

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
window.open("chatWindow.html?id=1", "Chat Window", "resizable=0,width=700,height=600");

 To Read Argument create js function in opening page and create following function

function getArgs() {
var args = new Object();
var query = location.search.substring(1);
var pairs = query.split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf('=');
    if (pos == -1) continue;
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0, pos);
    var value = pairs[i].substring(pos + 1);
    args[argname] = unescape(value);
}
return args;
```

}
  then use
      var args = getArgs();
      var  hid =args.id;

Comment: And then, how to access it inside the window?

Comment: Sir, I'm sorry but this is a bit too complex for me!

Comment: Ohkay  i tried to create an object which will store information of all the parameters passed for ex if you want to send two infomation name and color then you can call the method getArgs() it will return an object with sent information ex args.name and args..color you can also check whether one of the information is sent or not eg if(args.color) if color is sent then use the variable.